# Why it is printing i value (it is already outside the scope)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In JavaScript why `i` value is printed when we are printing outside the scope

```
test();
function test(){

    for(var i=0;i<10 ;i++){
        console.log(i)
    }
    console.log('outside'+i)
}
```

As comparison to Java it is giving compile error?

```
for(int x = 10; x < 20; x = x+1) {
   System.out.println("value of x : " + x );
}
System.out.print("value o " + x );
```

Comment: javascript use only function scoping, not block scoping

Comment: Also, It is good practice to use semicolons in JavaScript

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript has function scope not block scope (C, C#, C++, Java and many other programming languages have block scope). In JavaScript a variable defined anywhere inside the function will be visible anywhere in the function:

```
function test() {
  console.log(x); // logs undefined, because x is a variable that has no value yet

  if (true) {
    x = 42;
  } else {
    var x = 5; // x is not set to 5, but it is acknowledged as a variable
  }

  console.log(x); // logs 42 because the value in variable x has been set to 42
  console.log(y); // Error because y is not declared
}
```

One thing you might see mentioned regarding this is `var` hoisting. This means the JS interpreter will act as if all the `var` statements in a scope (function or global) are moved at the begining of that scope:

```
function foo() {
  console.log(x,y);
  var x = 4;
  var y = 2;
  var x = 0;
}

// is equivalent to:

function foo() {
  var x,y;
  console.log(x,y);
  x = 4;
  y = 2;
  x = 0;
}
```

More details on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)

Also, note the difference between `var` and [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) from ECMAScript6

Comment: @A.Wolff  I think you are mistaken. `bar()` -> Reference error, while `baz(); var baz = function(){};` -> TypeError. The first indicates that there is no such thing as bar, while the second indicates that you are calling something that can't be called (undefined).

Comment: Ok my bad, i see what you mean now ;)

Answer (score 1):

The scope of `i` in this case isn't the `for` loop, but the `test()` function.

Comment: it mean it take whole function ? in javascript

Comment: Yes, and if a variable is used but not declared locally it becomes global in scope.